# Killing a Python program using ctrl C

Tags: python, keyboard, ctrl, easygui

I have an assignment in school which i can't get around and i'm stuck with.

the assignment is to build a program that infinitly spews out random numbers in a EasyGUI messagebox ( Yeah i know EasyGUI is old xD )

this is my source code:

import easygui

```
while True:
    easygui.msgbox(random.randint(-100, 100))
```

The problem is that when i run this i can't get out of it. I should be allowed to use ctrl+C but that doesn't work. Am i missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd use Python `signal.signal` to assign my own handler to Ctrl+C, where my handler would change the value I test in the `while` from True to False.

Comment: Do you really have to  use easygui?

Comment: Yeah i have to. told my teacher that it was outdated since 2013, but he wants us to stick to it. Allready lost faith in that teacher xD.

Comment: @Jake, I tried using signal handlers but it had zero effect, I imagine you would need to attach the easygui to some root Tkinter object and handle it that way but I saw absolutely no examples of this in the docs. I added a way to check when x is pressed that will allow you to end the loop when x is pressed

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you can't use ctrl-c when using easygui, you can use ctrl-c when using the idle for example you can do

```
for i in range(1, 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000):
    print(i)
```

that will work, it won't on easygui, since i spews out frames one by one.its to slow

Answer (score 0):

using signalhandlers does not seem to be a trivial task when it comes to easygui, if you can work with quitting when `x` is pressed you can do the  following:

```
while True:
    e = easygui.msgbox(random.randint(-100, 100))
    if e is None:
        break
```

`e` will either be a string `"OK"` if you press ok or None if `x` is pressed so it is probably the simplest way to quit and end the loop.

Comment: This worked for me! not with ctrl C but just a normal close